# No private key when installing SSL certificates from GoDaddy via cPanel

Tags: https, cpanel

I am having troubles with installing ssl certificate.

The ssl was created on GoDaddy without using crt created by hosting cpanel. Now I have file in formats of crt, pem, p7b. When I upload the crt keys on cPanel of hosting, the private key doesn't autofill itself. How can I solve this issue? Is it possible to get private key on any files that I have?

My file names:

- `ded4cf7d4bxxxf.crt`
- `ded4cf7d4bxxxf.pem`
- `gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b`

Comment: The private key is probably in the `.pem` file. Open with with any editor and see if first line is `BEGIN PRIVATE KEY`.

Comment: Hey patrick! It starts with -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

Comment: So based on only the names, you do not have the key. Ask your certificate provider. But better to start from scratch as your key is private and should normally always be under your control.